# How to apply k-means algorithm on image in pyqgis?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I try to apply k-means clustering in qgis console like below shown in this site.[Unsupervised KMeans image classification](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/otb/learning/unsupervisedkmeansimageclassification.html)

```
processing.runalg('otb:unsupervisedkmeansimageclassification', 'D:\data\sub_66', 128,100, 5, 1000, 0.0001, 'D:\data\sub_66kmeans')
```

but it gives error like this.
[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is probably due to OTB not being installed. You can check this by going to:

```
Processing > Options... > Providers
```

And look for `Orfeo Toolbox (Image analysis)`. If no paths are set then you may need to install it. A recent question was asked on how to install this: [How to configure Orfeo toolbox in QGIS 2.18 on Windows 7 32-Bit?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229594/how-to-configure-orfeo-toolbox-in-qgis-2-18-on-windows-7-32-bit)

---

Once it is installed, you could then run your code. However, there are some things to notice:

- Use either forward slashes or double-back slashes when defining paths.
- You may also need to include the extension of the file (e.g. `'D:/data/sub_66.tif'`).
- Optional parameters (e.g. *Validity Mask*) need to be defined. But if you don't want to include it in the analysis, use `None`.
- There are two outputs: an image and a file (I specified it as a `.txt` file). These also should be included.

This is the code I used to produce the two outputs:

```
import processing
processing.runalg("otb:unsupervisedkmeansimageclassification",'D:/data/sub_66.tif', 128, None, 100, 5, 1000, 0.0001, 'D:/data/sub_66k_means.tif', 'D:/data/sub_66k_centroid.txt')
```