# Orfeo toolbox (OTB) algorithms in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis-3, orfeo-toolbox

I've been trying to understand if the OTB (Orfeo toolbox) algorithms can be used in QGIS 3.0.0-Girona but found no official documentation about it. Under the 'Available QGIS Data Provider Plugins' (**Help**--> **About**), OTB is not showing.

It also doesn't help to install via OS4GEOW as mentioned in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229594/how-to-configure-orfeo-toolbox-in-qgis-2-18-on-windows-7-32-bit) post, as this only works for QGIS 2.X (which did work in including the OTB algorithms for me). Furthermore, OTB nowadays shows as deprecated.

Does anyone know how to include the algorithms and/or whether a future integration is planned in a future QGIS 3.X version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The OTB provider was removed from QGIS 3.0. See the QGIS 3.0.0 changelog: http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.0.0/#removed-otb-lidartools-providers-from-processing

As long as nobody makes a QGIS plugin to add OTB as a processing provider, it isn't possible to use OTB in QGIS 3.0.

Comment: Hold on! There is ongoing work and the OTB-QGIS plugin have been completely rewritten recently. We hope to be able to provide this version in QGIS 3.1 in June. Don't hesitate if you can contribute (beta testing for instance). More information about the plugin:  https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/qgis-otb-plugin

Answer (score 3):

Here are some resources that may help,

1. https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/en/add-orfeo-toolbox-to-qgis-3-x/
2. https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/qgis-otb-plugin