# Orfeo TrainClassifier tool not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, orfeo-toolbox, image-classification

I have been using Orfeo Toolbox with QGIS (version 2.18.0) to do image classification.

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHDDBxlPcaM) tutorial on YouTube on the SVM classifier. I have followed steps 1 and 2 as described, and obtained output. However, in step 3, my dialog box produces no output and the following message:

```
ERROR: Parameter -classifier.svm.m does not exist in the application. 
Converting outputs
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm TrainImagesClassifier (svm) finished
```

Now it appears to me that this particular part of Orfeo toolbox does not seem to be installed properly. Is that so? Is there a way to fix it?

I do not have administrative privileges on my PC and cannot use [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/229601/122102) method to install the toolbox. I have downloaded binaries from the orfeo toolbox website directly and supplied the path to that folder in QGIS. Does that not work?

Comment: What QGIS version? Is step 1 (compute image statistics) producing an output? Try going to Processing --> Options --> General --> Keep dialog open after running algorithm, and looking at the log there

Comment: @15Step I have modified the question with details after implementing your suggestions.

Comment: I think the problem is mostly since the OTB version of the binaries you dled is not compatible with the  QGIS version. How did you "supply the path" to QGIS?

Comment: I navigated to Processing --> Options --> Providers and copy-pasted the path in the "values" field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because you have a recent version of OTB but an older QGIS. Unfortunately QGIS-OTB compatibility is not great accross all version. We are working on improving this in OTB. In the meantime you can try:

- Use a more recent QGIS (you may need admin rights on your computer)
- Use OTB directly, outside of QGIS to do your classification, then load the results into QGIS normally.